# How to set attribute value of layer with PHP MapScript?

Tags: mapserver, php, mapscript

How can I set attribute values of a layer object with MapScript?

I'm using MapServer version 5.0.3, the php_mapscript.so lib is loaded in my app context

I have a simple Mapfile:

```
MAP
    SIZE 500 500
    EXTENT -180 -90 180 90
    UNITS dd
    CONFIG "CPL_DEBUG" "ON"
    CONFIG      "MS_ERRORFILE" "/var/www/Data/Data/mapserver/mapserver.log"
    SYMBOLSET "/var/www/Data/Data/mapserver/symbols.sym"
    FONTSET "/var/www/Data/Data/mapserver/fontset.txt"

#--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# load lines
#--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    LAYER
        NAME "loadlines"
        TYPE POLYGON
        DATA "/var/www/Data/Data/mapserver/data/loadlines/loadlines.shp"
        STATUS ON
        OPACITY 100
        DEBUG 5

        CLASS #default coloring
            STYLE
              COLOR 0 0 0
              WIDTH 6
              #PATTERN 40 10 END
            END
            NAME "gust"
            OUTLINECOLOR 254 254 254
            COLOR 100 100 100
            #OPACITY 50
        END

        TEMPLATE "blank.html"
        DUMP TRUE # allow GML export
        PROJECTION
            "init=epsg:4326"
        END
        METADATA 
            "wms_title"     "ffg_test"     
            "wms_srs"       "EPSG:54004 EPSG:4269 EPSG:4326" 
        END 
    END 
END
```

Which I want to view by calling this PHP script:

```
<?php
$map_path="/var/www/Data/Data/mapserver/routeguardTemp/test/";

$map = ms_newMapObj($map_path."loadlines.map");
$layer = $map->getLayerByName('loadlines');
$layer->set('opacity', 10);
$image=$map->draw();
$image_url=$image->saveWebImage();

?>

 <HTML>
  <HEAD>
      <TITLE>Map</TITLE>
  </HEAD>
  <BODY>
      <IMG SRC=<?php echo $image_url; ?> >
  </BODY>
 </HTML>
```

The script should alter the opacity value of the layer, but there is no effect.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure about the old version of mapscript, the documentation is not available anymore. But for the latest version of PHP mapscript, the property of layer object is set via ['set' method](http://mapserver.org/mapscript/php/phpmapscript.html#layerobj).

```
int set(string property_name, new_value)
    Set object property to a new value.
```

So maybe you can try with:

```
$layer->set('opacity', 10);
```

Comment: allright, i'll have a try in the morning!

Comment: Great it works!